# When using tokens with expiration dates, is it best practice to force re-authentication or refresh expiration date on every call?

Tags: rest, authentication, push-notification, token, access-token

If I've authenticated a REST client and generated a token for them with an expiration date of 2 hours, is it bad practice to keep updating the expiration date every time the make a call (e.g. if they make a call in 1 hour, then the expiration date would move to be 1 hour later than when it was created)?

Or is it best practice to keep the expiration date and just force a re-authentication and then generate a totall new token?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the easiest way to implement this is letting the server to auto-refresh the token. You can use an internal policy to check the number of seconds/minutes/hours/days that have occurred from the expiration date to now. If the token's expiration date is less or equal than a number of seconds/minutes/hours/days defined, then the server will generate a new token (and will return it to the client). This is transparent to the client and avoid to re-authenticate and ask for the user's credentials again. However, if the expiration date is greater than the number of seconds/minutes/hours/days defined, then you force the re-authentication.

Other workarounds may work as well but this implementation works for me. Hope this helps you!